# not able to install apache solr 6.6.5 on mac

Tags: solr

I am using Macbook m2 and have java jdk 11 installed. For an old project, I need to install SOLR 6.6.5.
While following the instructions mentioned in the official documentation, not able to start the SOLR server. However, I am able to start the latest versions of SOLR(9.1.1).

Need to know from the community that I need to install JDK 8 for SOLR 6.5.5 or any other pointers, that can be shared.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does "not able to start" imply? What is the error message? What does the logs say? The reference guide for 6.6 should tell you which requirements a Solr installation would have: https://solr.apache.org/guide/6_6/installing-solr.html

Comment: It started working for me. JAVA JDK8 is needed to run SOLR 6.6.5 version.

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled JDK 11 and installed JDK 8 on my system. Then, it worked for me.